# Sum of the Divisors Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\sigma (n) < 2n$ for $n = 3^s 5^t$ (Hint: $3 \times 5 < 16 = 2 \times 2 \times 4$)

Workings:

Let $\sigma (n) = \sigma (3^s5^t)$

Observe that

$(3^{s+1})(5^{t+1})$

$< 15(3^s)(5^t)$

$<= 15(3^s)(5^t)$

$< 16(3^s)(5^t)$

Now I'm not to sure on what to do. The hint seems to say I should split up $16$ to $2 \times 2 \times 4$. But I do not see the point of that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\large{\sigma (3^s 5^t)}= \sigma(3^s)\sigma(5^t)= \dfrac{3^{s+1}-1}{2}\dfrac{5^{t+1} -1}{4}= \dfrac{(3^{s+1} -1)(5^{t+1}-1)}{8}< \dfrac{(3^{s+1}) 5^{t+1}}{8} $ can you proceed?

Comment: $<= \frac{15(3^s)(5^t)}{8} < \frac{16(3^s)(5^t)}{8} = 2(3^s)(q^t)$

Comment: exactly but instead of $q$ we have $5$ and $\large 3^s5^t = n$

Comment: Thanks. i wrote q there but accident.